# Plugin 'XXXX' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins

I want to create custom plugin for my cordova app.

i am following [this tutorial](http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Writing-a-native-iOS-plugin-for-PhoneGap)

I added this in config.xml

```
<feature name="MyTestPlugin">
    <param name="ios-package" value="MyTestPlugin" />
</feature>
```

And here is my plugin.js file's code

```
window.showDate = function(str, callback) {
cordova.exec(callback, function(err) {
             callback('Nothing to echo.');
      }, "MyTestPlugin", "cordovaGetCurrentDate", [str]);
};
```

And in my index.js file i added button click event as

```
var myBtn = document.getElementById("btn");
    myBtn.addEventListener('click',function(){
            alert("Button Clicked");
           window.showDate("", function(echoValue) {
                           alert(echoValue);
                           });
    }, false);
```

But when i run the app...it shows in xcode console -> `ERROR: Plugin 'MyTestPlugin' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.`

I don't know what i am doing wrong.
I tried to search on google and read some stackoverflow post but still not solved.

Comment: Things changed quite a lot since that tutorial, I posted a link to an updated one in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the plugin in cordova_plugin.js file
For Example:

```
{
"file":"plugins/cordova-mytestplugin/www/mytestplugin.js",
"id":"cordova-custom-mytestplugin.MyTestPlugin",
"clobbers":["navigator.mytestplugin"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be best served by setting up the plugin in its own folder with a proper plugin.xml file that describes how to install it properly, then using the Cordova CLI to install it into you app from that path on your local filesystem.

There's a tutorial on how to do this that I wrote [here](http://moduscreate.com/plugin-authoring-cordova-6-ios-android/), the process looks something like this:

- Use the "plugman" tool to create an initial plugin stub
- Edit the plugin.xml file that plugman creates to name the plugin, specify which files it uses
- Implement a common JavaScript interface, you'll need to edit the stub that plugman creates for you
- Implement any native code that you need
- Install your plugin into your Cordova app using cordova plugin add with relative path to where you made your plugin with plugman
- Test

Relevant sections of the Cordova documentation:

[Plugin Development Guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html)